# How to interpret the norm of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, geometry, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

What's geometric interpretation of the Euclidean (Frobenius) norm of the matrix?

*I know that vector norm is a vector's lenght but what is the matrix norm geometrically?*

Comment: Consider the matrix as the operator on your vector space. Imagine the unit ball in this space; apply your operator to that unit ball; the lenght of the longest vector in the image of the unit ball will be the norm of the operator

Comment: I heard its an iterpretation for m-norm. Is it works with euclidian one too?

Comment: this interpretation  doesn't really depends on which norm you choose, because it's based on general defenition of operator-norm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer was given by [Anton Zagrivin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/600008/anton-zagrivin).

> Consider the matrix as the operator on your vector space. Imagine the unit ball in this space; apply your operator to that unit ball; the lenght of the longest vector in the image of the unit ball will be the norm of the operator

Comment: This is a good description of the operator norm, but does not apply to the Frobenius norm, which is _not_ an operator norm. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54180/19147) is a good geometric description of the Frobenius norm.