# Ratio of first 2 moments of Hessian eigenvalues, name or other interpretations?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Suppose we have a positive semidefinite matrix $H$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and consider the following ratio of eigenvalue moments:

$$r=\frac{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\ldots+\lambda_n)^2}{\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\ldots+\lambda_n^2}=n \frac{\left(E\lambda\right)^2}{E\lambda^2}$$

This quantity seems to capture the difficulty of minimizing quadratic with Hessian $H$ better than condition number of $H$.

1. Does it have a name?
2. Does it come up in other interesting applications?

Interpretations I've found so far:

- a single step of gradient descent with starting weights initialized from standard normal may reduce expected loss by up $r$ in first step
- in the basis of eigenvectors of $X$, transform unit box by $H$, $\sqrt{r}$ now measures the ratio of lengths of longest diagonal using Manhattan vs Euclidian distance (from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54176/is-there-a-geometric-meaning-of-the-frobenius-norm))
- scale doesn't matter, so can normalize $\lambda$ to add up to 1. If we interpret $H$ as a quantum state with purity $\rho$, $r=1/\rho$. Alternatively, express it in terms of [linear entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purity_(quantum_mechanics)#Linear_entropy) of the eigenvalue distribution

$$r=\frac{1}{(1-H_L)}$$